# `gem install zookeeper -v '1.4.4'` on osx 10.8.4 fail (with error related to C99 mode)

Tags: rubygems, apache-zookeeper

My system is osx 10.8.4, doing `gem install zookeeper -v '1.4.4'` always get the following error:

`src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.c:42:1: error: redefinition of a 'extern inline' function 'hashtable_iterator_key' is not supported in C99 mode
hashtable_iterator_key(struct hashtable_itr *i)
^
src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.h:36:1: note: previous definition is here
hashtable_iterator_key(struct hashtable_itr *i)
^
src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.c:46:1: error: redefinition of a 'extern inline' function 'hashtable_iterator_value' is not supported in C99 mode
hashtable_iterator_value(struct hashtable_itr *i)
^
src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.h:45:1: note: previous definition is here
hashtable_iterator_value(struct hashtable_itr *i)
^`

Does anyone happen to know the reason?
Thanks!

P.S. doing `gem install zookeeper` could install the zookeeper 1.4.6 with no problem.

UPDATE: doing `CC=gcc-4.6 gem install zookeeper -v '1.4.4'` solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make this an answered question, I would like to supply a "proper" answer.

zookeeper appears to be meant to build on gcc.

OS X or better said Xcode (since Version 4.x) stopped using gcc as a default until they finally dropped gcc support alltogether.

They switched over to LLVM in combination with the clang frontend.

The only way to get around that issue without fiddling in the sources is to install gcc via something like homebrew - for example;

`brew install gcc47`

Once that is done, you may instruct your building / installation process to use that gcc by providing the matching CC (and/or CXX) environment variables;

`CC=gcc-4.7 CXX=g++-4.7`

The update to your question works because you had gcc4.6 installed previously. This may not be the case for more recent installations of OS X / Xcode, hence my verbose answer.

These steps should be rather generic and can be used whenever "standard" packages do not build or install properly on OS X / Xcode; simply prepend your installation/configuration instruction with the given environment variables.

As to your example that would be:

`CC=gcc-4.7 CXX=g++-4.7 gem install zookeeper -v '1.4.4'`

Note; there are most likely less invasive ways to get the job done, but without further try and error, the above mentioned usually does the job for all kinds of weird results in connection to clang / gcc incompatibilities.

Comment: For me it worked but without the CXX flag, it was breaking the build